# how to bind OnClick event to Singleton function?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to bind OnClick event of UI Button to a function in Singleton object. I tried to do that, but every time I go to other scene and get back to the old scene I find that object disappear from the onClick field in the inspector while it's exist in the hierarchy ! 
If it's not possible to do that, what's the alternative way ?
*Note: I'm using c#*

Comment: last time i tried, couldn't attach any static methods to the onclick..

Comment: I think it should work if the function you call is non static, but references the instance inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this guy had a similiar problem: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/335736/gameobject-still-destroyed-after-reloading-level.html

I would have posted this as a comment if I had enough reputation..

Comment: This guy in the Unity Forum, explained a lot what was the workaround: 

http://answers.unity3d.com/comments/872421/view.html

You must creating new object to preserve your Singleton Object on UI Button, handle it with other function to check for existing instances. cmiiw